# Views versus CALayers?

Tags: ios, macos, view, calayer

I want to build an application that lets me import a image file and scale the number of pixels to some number of feet (like a floorplan), and then overlay other images and elements.

Which is the better way to go if I want the application to be able to run on OSX and iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALayer and CoreGraphics are available on OSX and iOS. UIView and NSView are OSX/iOS equivalents but not identical.

Thus, your portability will be better if you use Core Graphics and CALayer. That said, your development speed may be quicker with friendly and simple views. I'm assuming that by answering this question you are relatively new to iOS and OSX - CoreGraphics is a relatively difficult subject if that is the case.

Also note that it is unlikely that you can (easily) completely divorce yourself from UIView.

Comment: Roger, thanks for the help ... You're right, I am new to iOS and OSX and the reading/studying I have been doing pointed to CoreGraphics and using CALayer, but I thought it wiser to ask more experienced developers, such as yourself.  Yes the learning curve is a bit steep right now, but at least I feel like I'm going in the right direction.  Thanks again.

Comment: > You're right... glad to help but please mark as answered :-)